# Nested Dict Python getting Keys and Max of value

Tags: python

I have dict something like this

```
d = { address { 'Avenue' : 3000,
                'Street' : 3000,
                'road' : 4000},
      movieprice {
                  'panda' : 40,
                   'fastandfurious' : 30,
                   'starwars': 50}}
```

I want out put something like this

```
address Avenue,Street,road 4000 ---> last Column should max of values max(3000,3000,4000)
movie panda,fastandfurious,starwars 50 --> max of value.
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your `d` is not a valid Python dictionary. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: how to sort dict by value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

What about this (assuming we fix your dictionary):

```
d = {'address': {'Avenue': 3000,
                 'Street': 3000,
                 'road': 4000},
     'movieprice': {'panda': 40,
                    'fastandfurious': 30,
                    'starwars': 50}}

for k, nested in d.items():
    print("%s %s, %d" % (k, ', '.join(nested.keys()), max(nested.values())))
```

Prints:

```
address Street, road, Avenue, 4000
movieprice panda, fastandfurious, starwars, 50
```

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. I have corrected my dict.

Answer (score 0):

To find the maximum value of a dictionary you can just do

```
d = some_dictionary
max(d.values())
```

That will give you the maximum value. As for finding which keys have that max value you'd have to iterate through the dictionary keys and test against `max(d.values())` because multiple keys could have the same value. So it'd be something like so

```
d = some_dictionary
max_value_keys = [d[x] for x in d.keys if d[x] == max(d.values())]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make your dictionary valid. If you're nesting it inside another dictionary, you have to define each dictionary as a value of a key-value pair. Here is the correct code:

```
d = { 'address' : { 'Avenue' : 3000,
            'Street' : 3000,
            'road' : 4000},
      'movieprice' : {
              'panda' : 40,
               'fastandfurious' : 30,
               'starwars': 50}}
```

From there, you can use Bah's solution to loop through the dictionaries and print their keys and the max of their values.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dictionary and print the values

```
import operator
d = {} # your nested dictonary
for k, nested in d.items():
    print k, ",".join([item[0] for item in sorted(nested.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))]), max(nested.values())
```

output:

```
movieprice fastandfurious,panda,starwars 50
address Avenue,Street,road 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for i in d:
    print i, ','.join(d[i].keys()), max(d[i].values())
```

---

```
>>> for i in d:
...     print i, ','.join(d[i].keys()), max(d[i].values())
... 
movieprice starwars,panda,fastandfurious 50
address Street,Avenue,road 4000
>>>
```